# Fluent Migrate Candidate Key

Tags: entity-framework-migrations, fluent-migrator

I have two tables One named "Root" which has columns `Id`,`RootNumber`, in which `Id` is primary Key.

Now when I tried to create another table with `RootNumber` as the foreign key I get below error

> InnerException    {"There are no primary or candidate keys in the
>   referenced table 'dbo.Root' that match the referencing column list in
>   the foreign key ("FK_CNTR_Root", \r\nCould not create constraint or
>   index. See previous errors."} System.Exception
>   {System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException}

```
 this.CreateTableWithId32("CNTR", "Id", s => s
            .WithColumn("CNTRNumber").AsString(10).NotNullable()
           .WithColumn("CNTRName").AsString(10).NotNullable()

            .WithColumn("RootNum").AsInt32().NotNullable()
                .ForeignKey("FK_CNTR_Root", "Root", "RootNumber")
```

Answer (score 0):

The error is very clear. You can make only the PrimaryKey column to be referenced as ForeignKey in another table. So Either make `Id` as a foreign key in other table or Change `RootNumber` to PrimaryKey of `Root` table.

Refer to this basic [Foreign Key](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_foreignkey.asp) definition.